# How to wait on child process to finish with time limit?

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

I would like to wait for a forked child process to finish execution, though I do not want to wait indefinitely, but *at most for given time, then kill the child* if still running.

[wait(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) on Linux says:

> Otherwise they block until either a child changes state or a signal handler interrupts the call (assuming that system calls are not automatically restarted using the SA_RESTART flag of sigaction(2)).

Can someone show me an example how should I set up a signal to *interrupt waiting* after a given time, and then to *continue execution*?

Comment: One option is to spawn a second timer child process, which will end and thus change state after a timer.  Then either the original child or the timer child can end the waiting state of the parent.

Comment: How accurate a time are you after?  Whole seconds OK, or sub-seconds required?

Comment: Waiting time should typically be 0.1 - 1 second.

Comment: For sub-second timing, check [`posix_settime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_settime.html) (preferred) or [`setitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html) (obsolescent, which may mean it is more widely supported).

Comment: After `fork` in the child process, call [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_CPU` before doing the `execve`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`alarm(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alarm) to set up a timer that will send `SIGALRM` to your process when it expires. [`kill(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) is one of the functions it's safe to call from a signal handler (see the [`signal(7)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal)), so you can just directly kill the child process from the `SIGALRM` handler and the blocking [`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) or [`wait(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait) you're doing on the main thread will return.

If you need higher resolution, you can use [`ualarm(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ualarm) instead.